# Why is my interpolation not working properly in my function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a fairly long code that processes spectra, and along the way I need an interpolation of some points. I used to have all this code written line-by-line without any functions, and it all worked properly, but now I'm converting it to two large functions so that I can call it on other models more easily in the future. Below is my code (I have more code after the last line here that plots some things, but that's not relevant to my issue, since I've tested this with a bunch of `print` lines and learned that my issue arises when I call the `interpolation` function inside my `process` function.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

# Required files and lists
filename = 'bpass_spectra.txt' # number of columns = 4
extinctionfile = 'ExtinctionLawPoints.txt' # R_V = 4.0
datalist = []
if filename == 'bpass_spectra.txt':
    filetype = 4
else:
    filetype = 1
if extinctionfile == 'ExtinctionLawPoints.txt':
    R_V = 4.0
else:
    R_V = 1.0 #to be determined

# Constants
h = 4.1357e-15 # Planck's constant [eV s]
c = float(3e8) # speed of light [m/s]

# Inputs
beta = 2.0 # power used in extinction law
R = 1.0 # star formation rate [Msun/yr]
z = 1.0 # redshift
M_gas = 1.0 # mass of gas
M_halo = 2e41 # mass of dark matter halo

# Read spectra file
f = open(filename, 'r')
rawlines = f.readlines()
met = re.findall('Z\s=\s(\d*\.\d+)', rawlines[0])
del rawlines[0]
for i in range(len(rawlines)):
    newlist = rawlines[i].split(' ')
    datalist.append(newlist)

# Read extinction curve data file
rawpoints = open(extinctionfile, 'r').readlines()
def interpolate(R_V, rawpoints, Elist, i):
    pointslist = []
    if R_V == 4.0:
        for i in range(len(rawpoints)):
            newlst = re.split('(?!\S)\s(?=\S)|(?!\S)\s+(?=\S)', rawpoints[i])
            pointslist.append(newlst)
        pointslist = pointslist[3:]
        lambdalist = [float(item[0]) for item in pointslist]
        k_abslist = [float(item[4]) for item in pointslist]
        xvallist = [(c*h)/(lamb*1e-6) for lamb in lambdalist]
        k_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(xvallist, k_abslist)
        return k_interp(Elist[i])

# Processing function
def process(interpolate, filetype, datalist, beta, R, z, M_gas, M_halo, met):
    speclist = []
    if filetype == 4:
        metallicity = float(met[0])
        Elist = [float(item[0]) for item in datalist]
        speclambdalist = [h*c*1e9/E for E in Elist]
        met1list = [float(item[1]) for item in datalist]
        speclist.extend(met1list)
        klist, Tlist = [None]*len(speclist), [None]*len(speclist)
        if metallicity > 0.0052:
            DGRlist = [50.0*np.exp(-2.21)*metallicity]*len(speclist) # dust to gas ratio
        elif metallicity <= 0.0052:
            DGRlist = [((50.0*metallicity)**3.15)*np.exp(-0.96)]*len(speclist)
        for i in range(len(speclist)):
            if Elist[i] <= 4.1357e-3: # frequencies <= 10^12 Hz
                klist[i] = 0.1*(float(Elist[i])/(1000.0*h))**beta # extinction law [cm^2/g]
            elif Elist[i] > 4.1357e-3: # frequencies > 10^12 Hz
                klist[i] = interpolate(R_V, rawpoints, Elist, i) # interpolated function's value at Elist[i]
        print "KLIST (INTERPOLATION) ELEMENTS 0 AND 1000:", klist[0], klist[1000]
        return
```

The output from the `print` line is `KLIST (INTERPOLATION) ELEMENTS 0 AND 1000: 52167.31734159269 52167.31734159269`.

When I run my old code without functions, I print `klist[0]` and `klist[1000]` like I do here and get different values for each. In this new code, I get back two values that are the same from this line. This shouldn't be the case, so it must not be interpolating correctly inside my function (maybe it's not performing it on each point correctly in the loop?). Does anyone have any insight? It would be unreasonable to post my entire code with all the used text files here (they're very large), so I'm not expecting anyone to run it, but rather examine how I use and call my functions.

Edit: Below is the original version of my code up to the interpolation point without the functions (which works).

```
import re
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

filename = 'bpass_spectra.txt'
extinctionfile = 'ExtinctionLawPoints.txt' # from R_V = 4.0
pointslist = []
datalist = []
speclist = []

# Constants
h = 4.1357e-15 # Planck's constant [eV s]
c = float(3e8) # speed of light [m/s]

# Read spectra file
f = open(filename, 'r')
rawspectra = f.readlines()
met = re.findall('Z\s=\s(\d*\.\d+)', rawspectra[0])
del rawspectra[0]
for i in range(len(rawspectra)):
    newlist = rawspectra[i].split(' ')
    datalist.append(newlist)

# Read extinction curve data file
rawpoints = open(extinctionfile, 'r').readlines()
for i in range(len(rawpoints)):
    newlst = re.split('(?!\S)\s(?=\S)|(?!\S)\s+(?=\S)', rawpoints[i])
    pointslist.append(newlst)
pointslist = pointslist[3:]
lambdalist = [float(item[0]) for item in pointslist]
k_abslist = [float(item[4]) for item in pointslist]
xvallist = [(c*h)/(lamb*1e-6) for lamb in lambdalist]
k_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(xvallist, k_abslist)

# Create new lists
Elist = [float(item[0]) for item in datalist]
speclambdalist = [h*c*1e9/E for E in Elist]
z1list = [float(item[1]) for item in datalist]
speclist.extend(z1list)
met = met[0]
klist = [None]*len(speclist)
Loutlist = [None]*len(speclist)
Tlist = [None]*len(speclist)

# Define parameters 
b = 2.0 # power used in extinction law (beta)
R = 1.0 # star formation ratw [Msun/yr]
z = 1.0 # redshift
Mgas = 1.0 # mass of gas
Mhalo = 2e41 # mass of dark matter halo

if float(met) > 0.0052:
    DGRlist = [50.0*np.exp(-2.21)*float(met)]*len(speclist)
elif float(met) <= 0.0052:
    DGRlist = [((50.0*float(met))**3.15)*np.exp(-0.96)]*len(speclist)
for i in range(len(speclist)):
    if float(Elist[i]) <= 4.1357e-3: # frequencies <= 10^12 Hz
        klist[i] = 0.1*(float(Elist[i])/(1000.0*h))**b # extinction law [cm^2/g]
    elif float(Elist[i]) > 4.1357e-3: # frequencies > 10^12 Hz
        klist[i] = k_interp(Elist[i]) # interpolated function's value at Elist[i]
print "KLIST (INTERPOLATION) ELEMENTS 0 AND 1000:", klist[0], klist[1000]
```

The output from this `print` line is `KLIST (INTERPOLATION) ELEMENTS 0 AND 1000 7779.275435560996 58253.589270674354`.

Comment: Maybe share the original version without the function?

Comment: @wowserx Sure, I'll edit that in

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Show the output you got, the output you expected, and your tracing of intermediate results or other useful debugging attempts.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are entering the `interpolate` function (`Elist[i] > 4.1357e-3`) and that `R_V = 4.0` within `process`?

Comment: Yes, I already did that in my error check process and can confirm both of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `i` as an argument to `interpolate`, and then also using `i` in a loop within `interpolate`. Once `i` is used within the `for i in range(len(rawpoints))` loop in `interpolate`, it will be set to some value: `len(rawpoints)-1`. The `interpolate` function will then always return the same value `k_interp(Elist[i])`, which is equivalent to `k_interp(Elist[len(rawpoints)-1])`. You will need to either define a new variable within your loop (e.g. `for not_i in range(len(rawpoints))`), or use a different variable for the `Elist` argument. Consider the following change to `interpolate`:

```
def interpolate(R_V, rawpoints, Elist, j):
    pointslist = []
    if R_V == 4.0:
        for i in range(len(rawpoints)):
            newlst = re.split('(?!\S)\s(?=\S)|(?!\S)\s+(?=\S)', rawpoints[i])
            pointslist.append(newlst)
        pointslist = pointslist[3:]
        lambdalist = [float(item[0]) for item in pointslist]
        k_abslist = [float(item[4]) for item in pointslist]
        xvallist = [(c*h)/(lamb*1e-6) for lamb in lambdalist]
        k_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(xvallist, k_abslist)
        return k_interp(Elist[j])
```